# Why Prisma transforms my `or` condition to an `and` one?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I'm trying to create a NestJS `findOne` service method that takes an `identifier` and returns first user with `id` or `email` or `nickname` that is this identifier.

It looks like this:

```
  findOne(identifier: string) {
    return this.prisma.user.findFirstOrThrow({
      where: {
        OR: [
          {
            id: identifier,
            email: identifier,
            nickname: identifier,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
```

It returns no result because the output query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT "public"."users"."id",
       "public"."users"."firstName",
       "public"."users"."lastName",
       "public"."users"."email",
       "public"."users"."nickname",
       "public"."users"."createdAt",
       "public"."users"."updatedAt"
FROM "public"."users"
WHERE (
        "public"."users"."id" = $1
    AND "public"."users"."email" = $2
    AND "public"."users"."nickname" = $3
) LIMIT $4 OFFSET $5
```

As you can see, it applies a `AND` condition, not a `OR` one.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You only have one item in your `OR` array. You need to put each one of `id`, `email`, `nickname` as a separate item into the array, not together in one item…!?

Comment: Oh my god so dumb... Thanks @deceze it now works as expected !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @deceze for help.
The problem was simple to solve. I had

```
indOne(identifier: string) {
    return this.prisma.user.findFirstOrThrow({
      where: {
        OR: [
          {
            id: identifier,
            email: identifier,
            nickname: identifier,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
```

that must be replaced by

```
  findOne(identifier: string) {
    return this.prisma.user.findFirstOrThrow({
      where: {
        OR: [
          {
            id: identifier,
          },
          {
            email: identifier,
          },
          {
            nickname: identifier,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  }
```

since `OR` must have multiple items in its array.